# Creating a general hibernate query that works with the LEN or LENGTH function

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, hibernate

In one of my database services, I create a hibernate query as follows:

```
createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM documentheaders order by LEN(header) DESC").addEntity(Documentheaders.class);
```

This works great as long as I am using MS SQL.   If I try to run this query with MYSQL I get a sql error because in MYSQL, the correct function is LENGTH.    Is there any way to create a single sql query that will cover both dialects (I know I can check the database type and use separate queries for each kind of database but I'm hoping for something more elegant.

Thanks,

Elliott

Comment: there is a length() function in HQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thanks to frictionlesspulley for alerting me to the HQL function.   That solved the problem.

Comment: could you improve your answer to contain a complete solution, with an example. This will also help others finding your question.